# When I bulk publish many posts in WordPress, the post archive order changes from time to time

Tags: wordpress

I'm bulk publishing many posts that were programmatically created in draft.

What's happening? That the posts order in archives changes from time to time.
I guess that when the wpquery inner cache expires, the post order is newly calculated and then.. changes.

But why?
I've tried with many different themes, even TwentyTwenty but this keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you bulk publish that many posts, all of them have the same date of pubblication, even the same second.

This is not a problem when we're talking 'about few post, but may be with more and more posts (even 100 is enough).

In fact, if you programmatically create them as published, you've no problem at all, 'cause not all of them are published in the same second.

This is happening only in frontend wpquery, in backend there's no problem at all since WP is using milliseconds.
Why this is a reality, I really don't know.